# Error mask using keyup jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have `ìnput type=text` and maxleng=`3` in pattern, my result perfect 1,78, but solution error print value = `1,00` this is my code:

```js
$("#field").keyup(function() {
  var valor = parseFloat(this.value.match(/[0-9]*/));
      $("#field").val(valor.toFixed(2).replace('.',','));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="field" type="text" pattern="([0-9]{3})"/>
```

How do I make `123` when the value is `1,23`?

Comment: You don't need maxlength with the pattern you've applied, although your pattern doesn't allow decimal characters

Comment: Yes I had been trying as `input number` and forgot to remove, edited a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ques. is "How do I make 123 when the value is 1,23?" if i am not wrong you are looking for this solution

```js
$("#field").keyup(function() {
  $("#field").val(this.value.replace('.',''));
  $("#field").val(this.value.replace(',',''));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="field" type="text" pattern="([0-9]{3})"/>
```

Ok. For this ques "Input value is 123 and  the output value is 1,23?"

```js
$("#field").keyup(function() {
    var valor = parseFloat(this.value.match(/[0-9]*/));
    if (this.value.length==3){
      var s = this.value.slice(0, 1) + "," + this.value.slice(1, 3) ;
      $("#field").val(s);
    }
   
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input id="field" type="text" pattern="([0-9]{3})"/>
```

Comment: I want to type 123 and automatically be transformed to 1,23